# How can GDB determine whether it is attached or actually running a process?

Tags: gdb

Sometimes I run GDB using the "--pid" command argument, and sometimes I use gdb to "run" a program.  If I want 1 gdb command file to use in both situtations, I have a problem because you cannot continue a process that is not running, and you cannot type "run" when a process is running.

I.e. here's a simple command file:

```
br main.c:30
commands
p foo
c
end
# what can i put here, so that the command file will work in both situations?
```

If I put "run" in the command file, when I attach to a process, it will actually stop the current process and run a new one (I definitely don't want this).
If I put "c" in the command file, then when I try to use "gdb --command=commandfile --args process arg1 arg2", then it will say "there's no process running".

This is useful because if I have a complicated set of commands I want to use, it is useful to have the flexibility to be able to load them on both processes before they start and on processes which are already running, without maintaining 2 exact copies where the last line is different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this information from Python.  Specifically, you want to get the Inferior object and then examine its was_attached attribute.  You could, for instance, use this to write a "run-or-continue" command (in Python) and then just use that from the CLI.

Comment: If I had a python-enabled gdb, I could probably go this route.  I see the "info inferiors" is pretty limited from the gdb CLI.  Is there any other way to get at the was_attached attribute?